# Nativescript 4.2 timeline-view

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I run timeline-view in version 4.2 of nativescrip to see the tree but I have an error when viewing the graphics in the browser, nothing just appears and in javascript I have the following:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0.
    at redrawBackground (file:///Users/alanneri/Documents/Nativescript/app-mrsinco/times.html:223:32)
    at file:///Users/alanneri/Documents/Nativescript/app-mrsinco/times.html:320:1
times.html:223 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0.
    at redrawBackground (file:///Users/alanneri/Documents/Nativescript/app-mrsinco/times.html:223:32)
    at file:///Users/alanneri/Documents/Nativescript/app-mrsinco/times.html:274:5
times.html:223 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0.
    at redrawBackground (file:///Users/alanneri/Documents/Nativescript/app-mrsinco/times.html:223:32)
    at file:///Users/alanneri/Documents/Nativescript/app-mrsinco/times.html:313:9
times.html:223 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0.
    at redrawBackground (file:///Users/alanneri/Documents/Nativescript/app-mrsinco/times.html:223:32)
    at file:///Users/alanneri/Documents/Nativescript/app-mrsinco/times.html:274:5
15times.html:223 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0.
    at redrawBackground (file:///Users/alanneri/Documents/Nativescript/app-mrsinco/times.html:223:32)
    at file:///Users/alanneri/Documents/Nativescript/app-mrsinco/times.html:313:9
```

Comment: Make sure that the profiling argument is in `app/package.json` and not in the main `package.json`. Also, try changing the terminal (I had some issues with `bash` and timeline)

Comment: I'm going to check right now, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, I was misplacing the profiling argument @NickIliev

Comment: Adding the comment as an answer for more visibility

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the profiling argument is in **`app/package.json`** and not in the main package.json. Full details on how to use timeline-view can be found [here](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/deep-dive-into-nativescript-3.1-performance-improvements)